# Value not set to global variable in JS/AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, angular-services, angular-factory

I am using `gulp` to run and build to run my application. I am getting file contents using `$http` service in my `index.js` file  and then setting value of a variable like

`window.variablex = "http://localhost:8080/appname"`.

here is how I am doing it (in `index.js`)

```
(function ()
 {
  'use strict';

   angular
    .module('main')
    .controller('IndexController', IndexController);
function IndexController($http){
   $http.get('conf/conf.json').success(function(data){

     window.variable = data.urlValue;

  }).error(function(error){
    console.log(error);
  });
    }
});
```

And I've created a factory to call the rest APIs of my backend application like

```
(function(){

  'use strict';

   angular
   .module('main')
   .factory('testService',['$resource',testService]);
     function agentService($resource){
 var agents = $resource('../controller/',{id:'@id'},
  {

    getList:{
      method:'GET',
      url:window.variable+"/controller/index/",
      isArray:false
}
});
```

Now, I except a rest call to made like

`http://localhost:8080/appname/controller`

But it always sends a call like `http://undefined/appname/controller` which is not correct.

I can get the new set value anywhere else, but this value is not being set in `resource service` objects somehow.
I am definitely missing something.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kenji Mukai's answer did work but I may have to change configuration at run time and there it fails. This is how I achieved it (in case anyone having an issue setting variables before application gets boostrap)

These are the sets that I followed

1. Remove `ng-app="appName"` from your `html` file as this is what causing problem. Angular hits this tag and bootstraps your application before anything else. hence application is bootstratped before loading data from server-side (in my case)
2. Added the following in my main module

   ```
   var injector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
   var http = injector.get("$http");
      return http.get("conf/conf.json").then(function(response){
       window.appBaseUrl = response.data.gatewayUrl
         }).then(function bootstrapApplication() {
            angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ["yourModuleName"]);
           });
        });
   ```

This will load/set new values everytime you refresh your page. You can change `conf.json` file even at runtime and refreshing the page will take care of updating the values.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Gulp, I advise you to use [gulp-ng-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-config)

For example, you have your config.json:

```
{
  "local": {
    "EnvironmentConfig": {
      "api": "http://localhost/"
    }
  },
  "production": {
    "EnvironmentConfig": {
      "api": "https://api.production.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, the usage in gulpfile is:

```
gulp.task('config', function () {
    gulp.src('config.json')
        .pipe(gulpNgConfig('main.config', {
            environment: 'production'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});
```

You will have this output:

```
angular.module('myApp.config', [])
.constant('EnvironmentConfig', {"api": "https://api.production.com/"});
```

And then, you have to add that module in your app.js

```
angular.module('main', [ 'main.config' ]);
```

To use that variable you have to inject in your provider:

```
angular
    .module('main')
    .factory('testService', ['$resource', 'EnvironmentConfig', testService]);
function agentService($resource, EnvironmentConfig) {

    var agents = $resource('../controller/', {id: '@id'},
        {

            getList: {
                method: 'GET',
                url: EnvironmentConfig + "/controller/index/",
                isArray: false
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: let me give it a try. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Although this worked but I may have to change configurations at run time, when application is deployed and I don't want to tweak into `module` with constants , created by this gulp task.
Anyways, thanks for taking time